# fixing an error and finishing a python code

Tags: python

So I am making a Spirograph that first made itself into 12 triangles and now I want to make a circle to go along side it( I hope that makes sense) here is the code for it right now

```
   from graphics import *
from math import *


def ar(a):
    return a*3.141592654/180

def spiral(x0,y0,win):
    startangle = 60
    stepangle = 120
    radius = 50
    p1 = Point(x0 + radius * cos(ar(startangle)), y0 + radius * sin(ar(startangle)))
    for step in range(12):
        startangle += 30
        for i in range((stepangle+startangle),(360+stepangle+startangle),stepangle):
            p2 = Point(x0 + radius * cos(ar(i)), y0 + radius * sin(ar(i)))
            Line(p1,p2).draw(win)
            p1 = p2

def doublespiral():
    win = GraphWin("stuff",800,800)
    x1 = 400
    y1 = 400
    radius1 = 100
    startangle1 = 60
    stepangle1 = 120
    p1 = Point(x1 + radius1 * cos(ar(startangle1)), y1 + radius1 * sin(ar(startangle1)))
    for steps in range(12):
        startangle1 += 30
        for i in range((stepangle1+startangle1),(360+stepangle1+startangle1), stepangle1):
            p2 = Point(x1 + radius1 * cos(ar(i)), y1 + radius1 * sin(ar(i)))

spiral(p1,p2,win)
input("<ENTER> to quit...")
win.close()

def main():
    doublespiral()


main()
```

Below is the full error it gave me

```
in spiral(x0, y0, win)
14     stepangle = 120
15     radius = 50
16 <----   p1 = Point(x0 + radius * cos(ar(startangle)), y0 + radius * sin(ar(startangle)))
17     for step in range(12):
18         startangle += 30

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instance' and 'float'
```

but when I run said code I keep getting this error"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instance' and 'float' " Can someone tell me what the error is so I understand how to fix it/avoid in future codes and also how I can fix it?

Comment: While many of us would be happy to help answer your question, [edit]ing your question to include the **full traceback** (line numbers, stack, all that gobbledygook) will help focus our efforts.

Comment: Yes, which line was this error occurring in?

Comment: Okay so I added the full error to the code, and how do I do the full traceback for future reference?

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a guess here, because you haven't posted the trace, but it may due to these lines:

```
def spiral(x0,y0,win):
    ...
    p1 = Point(x0 + radius * cos(ar(startangle)), y0 + radius * sin(ar(startangle)))
    ...

spiral(p1,p2,win)
```

If `p1` is of type `Point` and you pass it to spiral, where it is `x0`, then adding them as you do here

```
p1 = Point(x0 + radius * cos(ar(startangle)), y0 + radius * sin(ar(startangle)))
```

would fail because you cannot add an `instance` (`x0`) to a `float` (`radius`).